# Search for ".myox" files on Computer

Tags: c#, windows

trying to write a small windows application for my company. the part i am stuck at the moment is trying to search the computer for ".myox" files (or say any file type). Below pasted is the code i have worked out. I am an amateur programmer trying to get started with coding. The issue am having at the moment with the code below is its skipping almost all locations on the computer with the exception coming up as "access denied". I have run the VS as admin, and i am an admin on the computer as well. Not sure what i am missing, but if someone can point me in the right direction, that would be amazing.

```
private void FindAllFiles()
{
int drvCount;
int drvSearchCount = 0;
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
drvCount = allDrives.Count();

foreach (DriveInfo dr in allDrives)
{
  lbAllFiles.Items.Clear();
  drvSearchCount++;

  //removable drives
  if (!dr.IsReady)
  break;

  foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(dr.ToString()))
  {
    try
    {
      foreach (string files in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.myox"))
      {
        lbAllFiles.Items.Add(files);
      }

    }
    catch (Exception Error)
    {

    }
 }

if (drvSearchCount == drvCount)
break;
}

MessageBox.Show("Done searching your computer");
}
```

Thanks in Advance.
-Manu

Comment: You can try `FileIOPermission permission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, directory);
permission .AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, file); permission.Demand();`

Answer (score 1):

I see few "potential" issues and will list them below.

First is that you're doing this on main ( **UI** ) thread which will block whole application giving you no feedback about current state. You can use `Thread` to get rid of this problem. Outcome from this operation will produce another issue which is accessing `lbAllFiles` because ( as i think ) it's part of the UI. You can easily get rid of this problem making a `List<string>` that can be filled during `FindAllFiles` operation and then assigned into `lbAllFiles.Items`.

Second issue is :

```
foreach (string files in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.myox"))
{
    lbAllFiles.Items.Add(files);
}
```

`Directory.GetFiles(...)` will return only the files that are matching your `pattern` parameter so you can simply do :

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.myox");
if ( files != null && files.Length > 0 )
    lblAllFiles.Items.AddRange(files);
```

And finaly to get ( or check ) permission you can `Demand()` permissions as I've posted in the comment :

```
  foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(dr.ToString()))
  {
    FileIOPermission permission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, dir);
    try
    {
        permission.Demand();
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.myox");
        if ( files != null && files.Length > 0 )
            lblAllFiles.Items.AddRange(files);
    }
    catch (Exception Error)
    {

    }
 }
```

Let me know if that helped you. If not I'll try to update my answer with another solution.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Am just having a minor issue now though. For example i have an ".myox' file on the desktop, but the program catches an exception saying - 'Access to the path C\users\all users\microsoft\windows\systemdata is denied' and then it skips to C\Windows folder, and doesnt look for other sub folders under Users (C\users\Manu\desktop\) which is where the file is. Is there something else that needed to be added?
Highly appreciate you taking your time to answer my query.

Answer (score 1):

One thing i noticed in your code, is that you're not navigating through ALL directories and sub-directories. For that, where you call the GetDirectories function, not only send the path, but use the enumerator Alldirectories:

```
foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(dr.ToString(),System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```